# How to make a content type field unique per user

Tags: 7, entities, users, datetime

I want a date field to be unique per user so they can't add two nodes with the same date. I have **Unique Field** installed. Unfortunatly, they don't offer user scope.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Scorchio for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to achieve what I wanted putting this code in a custom module :

```
function node_calendar_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) //alter the form
{
  if($form_id == 'training_node_form') //specify form with form id
  {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate_function'; //declare a custom validation function
  }

}

function my_custom_validate_function($form, &$form_state)
{
    global $user; //because I needed the uid
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $dates_array = array(); //this will contain the dates to check for

    $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'training')
    ->propertyCondition('uid', $user->uid); //my query, checks for content type and current uid

    $trainings_query = $query->execute();

    if ($trainings_query) { //if query is successful
       $session_nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($trainings_query['node'])); //load the nodes
       foreach ($session_nodes as $training) {
           array_push($dates_array, substr($training->field_training_date['und'][0]['value'], 0, -9)); //push the dates in $dates_array after trimming the 00:00:00
       }
    }
    if (in_array(substr($form_state['values']['field_training_date']['und']['0']['value'], 0, -9), $dates_array)) { //if the date is already used
       form_set_error('field_training_date', t("Vous avez déjà un entrainement pour cette date. Veuillez modifier l'entrainement ou pour éviter de la duplication de contenu.")); //throw in error
    }
}
```

I commented my code for anyone who would like to do something like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Unique Field module, but I have a suggestion instead.

Create a little utility module which alters the node form of that node type and adds a *custom validation*. That validation could check for anything on the form, date inclusive.

In the Drupal 6 days [it worked like this](http://www.webscaped.com/articles/2009/03/custom-field-validation-in-drupal/). I hope this is enough for a starting point. [Also, reading the book [Pro Drupal 7 Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430228385) can help you a lot if you haven't written a module yet.]

Comment: I've created a basic module before. Basically, I would have to check in the database if the value of my date field is already present for the user? I'll start making the date field required with a custom module and then continue from there. Thanks alot for this starting point.

Comment: "Basically, I would have to check in the database if the value of my date field is already present for the user?" - yes, that's the validation criteria. You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal module https://drupal.org/project/field_validation does this. Just add a "Unique values" validator to the field and set the scope to "entity" or "bundle". There is then an option for "Per user" uniqueness across the field.

Answer (score 0):

The user scope functionality you are asking for is available in [Unique Field Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field) by default. There is an option called **"Choose whether values must be unique individually or in combination"**. Select  **"The combination of values from the specified fields must be unique"** option. And for the fields select your required field (date field in your case) along with the **author field**.

[image]